# How do epiR's epi.2by2 functions calculate odds ratios (ORs) and CIs, and why don't they match by hand calculations?

Tags: r, odds-ratio, epidemiology

I've seen a number of related questions using by-hand calcuations for the OR, but I'm interested in using the epi.2by2 functions in epiR.  Given a 2 by 2 cross-sectional table as below (q2.m), a single call to epi should do it:

```
q2.m = matrix(c(45,14,22,33), nrow=2, byrow=T, 
              dimnames = list(c("High dose", "Low dose"),c("fav", "unfav")))
epi.2by2(q2.m)
```

...yields...

```
         Outcome +    Outcome -      Total        Prevalence *        Odds
Exposed +           45           14         59                76.3       3.214
Exposed -           22           33         55                40.0       0.667
Total               67           47        114                58.8       1.426

Point estimates and 95 % CIs:
---------------------------------------------------------
Prevalence ratio                             1.91 (1.34, 2.72)
Odds ratio                                   4.75 (2.01, 11.75)
Attrib prevalence *                          36.27 (19.38, 53.17)
Attrib prevalence in population *            18.77 (2.98, 34.56)
Attrib fraction in exposed (%)               47.56 (25.31, 63.18)
Attrib fraction in population (%)            31.94 (13.12, 46.68)
---------------------------------------------------------
 * Cases per 100 population units
```

But that OR looks a bit odd.  The cross product OR (45x33)/(14x22) = 4.82.  Or seen another way, the ratio of the reported odds (3.214 / 0.667) = 4.82.

So what's that OR=4.75 referring to?!  I'm confused.  Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number 4.75 is a (bona fide) estimate of the population odds ratio. The help page for `epi.2by2()` tells you:

> Point estimates and confidence intervals the odds ratio are calculated using the exact method (using function `fisher.test`).

And the help page for `fisher.test()` tells you:

> Note that the conditional Maximum Likelihood Estimate (MLE) rather than the unconditional MLE (the sample odds ratio) is used.

The ‘conditional’ part is because you’re conditioning on both marginals being fixed by design (which, BTW, gives you a *conservative* test and confidence interval when they’re not).

The conditional ML estimate and the sample odds are usually *very* close, unless you have very few events/non-events (and then the confidence interval will be very wide anyway).

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks.  Any ideal way to get the sample OR and CI?    I've seen a few different libraries...?

Comment: @MikeDolanFliss The sample OR is easy enough to calculate manually (`x[1]*x[4]/x[2]/x[3]` in R code). And there are several R packages which can calculate it too (e.g. the `epicalc` package with its `cc()` function). The recommended CI to report depends on how many margins are fixed by design (zero, one or two).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the parameters to your function call are not the same. 
I get Odds Ratio of 4.82 just like the cross product you have shown.

epi.2by2(tab2, method="cohort.count", conf.level=.95)

```
         Outcome +    Outcome -      Total        Inc risk *        Odds
```

Exposed +           45           22         67              67.2       2.045
Exposed -           14           33         47              29.8       0.424
Total               59           55        114              51.8       1.073

### Point estimates and 95 % CIs:

Inc risk ratio                               2.25 (1.41, 3.61)
**Odds ratio                                   4.82 (2.15, 10.80)**
Attrib risk *                                37.38 (20.13, 54.62)
Attrib risk in population *                  21.97 (6.00, 37.94)
Attrib fraction in exposed (%)               55.65 (29.06, 72.27)

### Attrib fraction in population (%)            42.45 (17.16, 60.01)

X2 test statistic: 15.455 p-value: < 0.001
 Wald confidence limits
 * Outcomes per 100 population units